# assigning js value to php

Tags: php, javascript, variables

so I have this in my HTML file

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="load.js"> </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="load2.php"> </script>
```

Saw somewhere you could call an external php file using the js script tag and whatever js in the php file would be rendered first.
But my problem is, I can't assign no JS variable from load.js to a php variable in load2.php but, however, I could alert using `echo "alert(js variable);";` So that tells me it finds the variable and I could use it, but I can't assign it to a php variable :/ any help please?

Comment: You would need to use Ajax. Here's a quick tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm

Comment: you can only pass data from js to php via ajax, get request or form submissions.. something like `load.php?var=value` then you can get it on load.php via `$_GET['var']` which will return 'value'

Comment: PHP is a server-side language.  JavaScript is a client-side language.  PHP and JavaScript can't share variables; they run at different times.  `load2.php` will run, return a JavaScript file, which will be ran by the browser.

Comment: You should really understand the server-client platform before doodling with web programming.

Comment: And here's another Ajax tutorial which seems pretty good http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html

Comment: @RocketHazmat probably worth noting that JS can use PHP variables, just not the other way around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass javascript variables to php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754386/pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: @user2532739 they can't unless you pass them from client to server vice versa.. (JS can request via ajax,etc) and PHP can print back js variables/values like `<?php echo '<script> var js_variable = "'.$php_variable.'";</script>'; ?>` or something like that..

Comment: @reikyoushin I was saying JS can use PHP variables, for example `var jsVariable = <?php echo $phpVariable ?>;` Rocket seemed to be implying that it was difficult both ways, when I consider this direction fairly simple.

Comment: i just commented on the part where it says `just not the other way around.` because you can ajax request to a php file and the php file can print and return json, for example.. or in other words, i was just saying both can be done.. you just need to have them communicate with each other.. as in my last comment i used the word 'pass'

Comment: could anyone show me an example using ajax with js?

Answer (score 1):

When working between JavaScript and php you must remember one is client side (JavaScript) and the other server side (php). Therefore php can insert values into javascript before it is sent to the client and then rendered (processed). Although the reverse cannot happen as the "scope" of JavaScript is on the clients computer.

The way around this is to use AJAX requests from the client back to the server sending back the data / variable values you need.

JQuery provides an easy to use library with AJAX functionality.

Please see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side, JS is client side. This means the PHP will run far before the JS ever gets assigned. The only way a PHP file is going to get a JS variable is if you post it using Ajax

Comment: OR if you submit a form, or by using GET requests like in the comment i posted above..

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to dynamically load the PHP-generated script and pass some `GET` parameters to the PHP. This would still require ajax, but could be done cleanly with jQuery. If you go with jQuery, [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is the documentation for `getScript`.

EDIT

So, your HTML file should look like this:

```
<!-- your first javascript file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="load.js"></script>
<!-- load jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
    // get the variable from your first javascript file
    // via a getter function or global variable
    var x = getVarFromFirstFile();
    // this will load your second 'javascript' (generated by php) file
    // and will pass the variable 'x' as a GET parameter to the php
    $.getScript("load2.php?x="+x);
</script>
```

Then the php in load2.php could access the variable x (originally from load.js) like this:

```
 <?php
 $x = $_GET['x'];
 ...
```

Comment: So just put that script in my JS file and GET it using php?