# PHP $var automatically updated

Tags: php, ajax, variables

How can i use AJAX to do something like:

```
<input type="text" name="test">

<?php
$test = $_POST['test']; //need to set the var "on the fly" 
echo $test;
?>
```

I need that the php var $test is auto-updated with the text/numbers that users set on the input named "test"

LIVE EXAMPLE OF USE: [test](http://www.codetuts.altervista.org/test.php)

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please elaborate, you question is not clear.  Can you show what you've tried and what is it that you expect and what is not working?

Comment: What javascript/jquery have you tried?

Comment: What's the reason you need to update a server-side variable on the fly? This would involve making an AJAX request on each keypress, which will get very tedious. There's most likely a better way to approach this situation.

Comment: What's with the rash of "i need to set a PHP variable from JS" questions as of late?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass JS variable to php echo statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982295/pass-js-variable-to-php-echo-statement), and dozens of others.  ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/17978326, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17932184, ...)

Comment: none of my case...
Live example here: www.codetuts.altervista.org/test.php

Users can set the width and height of a print.
The max width of each piece is 60cm, so if user on width set 300cm
i wanna to display "on the fly" the calc.

See live example posted in the question

Comment: They all have exactly the same answer as the question you have asked -- and the first is exactly *the very question* you have asked (minus the difference between echoing the variable itself and echoing it as part of another string).  If you meant to ask a different question, then go right ahead.  But this one has already been answered many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you need to add more information to your question, but I'd start off by looking into [jQuery Ajax.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

---

As per your linked example is this what you mean? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XNnNb/2/).

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />

Base: <span id="base"></span>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#base').html($('#test').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm, i'm reading the link you told, but i need to finish it before vacation (-2days)..can please make a working fast example?
The result is like that:
(http://www.codetuts.altervista.org/test.php) but instead of pressing ENTER button, need to calculate it with no page refresh

Comment: Theres no ajax in the example you posted? I'll make something like what I think you want and update my answer

Comment: Corrected with what you want

Comment: Thanks, but js fiddle don't work. BTW i'll work on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX method from Jquery library

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "some.php",
 data: { test: "testData"}
 }).done(function( msg ) {
 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use jQuery..
Just add an onkeypressed listener, this will update you data:

```
<input onkeypressed="updatestuff();" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
     function updatestuff(){
         //ajax here
     }
</script>
```